# Mac OS X iterm2: backward delete word

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

I've been trying to customize a key shortcut to delete backspace entire word.
I've tried everything online and still this doesn't work.

I'm using iterm2, using `Natural Text Editing` keys preset and still - doing `command + delete` will delete the entire line, and doing `option + delete` will delete the last word up until a certain special character (this could be slash, hyphen, underscore, semicolon, etc...).

Doing `control + W` gives the same result as `option + delete`.

I do want the functionality of deleting backwards until a certain special character, but I would also like to be able to delete entire word (until space).

Comment: I do not really got your question. Why do you want control + W to delete backwards a word when option + delete already does this?

Comment: As I said, at the moment, both control + W and option + delete unfortunately do the same thing - delete a word up until a special character. I did not configure it like that, it is just the current situation. I want some keyboard shortcut to delete entire word until space, potentially to have it be assigned to control + W instead of its existing assignment

Comment: I need the same behavior too, deleting backward word by word until a special character would be killing me; for faster backward deletion, we need to have the `ctrl` + `w` to delete all the words back to the first `space` character. Linux does the same why not in mac?

Answer (score 5):

You may add corresponding keybinding to iterm2, or globally:

'Iterm2 preferences -> 'Keys' (or 'Profiles' -> 'Keys' - global | per-profile setting):

- add desired keyboard shortcut (e.g. option + shift + backspace),
- add Action - Under 'Send Keystrokes' select 'Send Hex Code' and type '0x17'

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I write in my terminal for example `word1 word2-word3` and press the shortcut it only deletes the `word3` part, and I want for it to delete the `word2-word3` completely

Comment: 0x17 - is required sequence. Do you see an action `Send Hex Codes: 0x17` opposite to your key combination? Is there a chance that your combination has been overriden somewhere else?
Try some other really specific combination, just for test.
I've added following mappings:
- Cmd+Backspace - `Send Hex Codes:0x15` (delete line),
- Option+Backspace - `Send Hex Codes:0x1b 0x7f` (delete 'part' of the word backwards),
- Option+Shift+Backspace - `Send Hex Codes:0x17` (delete word backwards).
Working as expected.

Comment: I have set all of these, tried `Option as meta` set on or off, none of those work.
Thanks for all the help anyway

Comment: Funny enough, I want the behavior you're seeing (and am getting the behavior you want, if I understand correctly) - I'd like `option + delete` to delete word characters up to a special character, but I'm getting the behavior with `0x17` of deleting the entire space-delimited string.

Comment: The different behaviour of `0x17` is likely due to your shell configuration WORDCHARS. See https://superuser.com/a/847842/21682 for example.